# postgresql:how to add a column and insert rows with three same values equally

Tags: sql, postgresql, sas, greenplum

I get a data set in greenplum(which runs postgresql sql syntax) and need to add a column with date type values(for SAS,however we could not use SAS data step) with three date:20170101,20170601,20171101 and each of these values with equally 1/3 of all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method for assigning the values randomly:

```
select (case row_number() over (order by random()) % 3
            when 0 then '2017-01-01'::date
            when 1 then '2017-06-01'::date
            when 2 then '2017-11-01'::date
        end) as dte
from t;
```

Note:  It would be faster to simply run:

```
select (case (random() * 3)::int
            when 0 then '2017-01-01'::date
            when 1 then '2017-06-01'::date
            when 2 then '2017-11-01'::date
        end) as dte
from t;
```

However, using `row_number()` guarantees an even balance between the three dates (as close as possible given the number of rows).